# Initialize StateProvider in FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, state, provider, riverpod

My app starts with retrieving data that is important throughout the flow of the app `mainContent`. Most of this data is static

#### Navigation screens

```
 Widget stackPages(WidgetRef ref) {
   AsyncValue<Map<String, Object>> mainContent = ref.watch(mainContentFutureProvider);
   return mainContent.when(
     loading: () => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
     error: (e, st) => Center(child: Text("Error: " + e.toString() + " " + st.toString())), 
     data: (content) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            _buildOffstageNavigator(ref, "Home", content),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(ref, "Page1", content),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(ref, "Page2", content),
            _buildOffstageNavigator(ref, "Page3", content)
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

#### content retrieval (mainContentFutureProvider)

```
final mainContentFutureProvider= FutureProvider<Map<String, Object>>((ref) async {
    List response = await Future.wait([
       DataController.userInfoDB.getUsers(),
       DataController.userInfoDB.getAnotherList(),
       DataController.userInfoDB.getAnotherList,
    ]);

    return {
      "users": response[0],
      "some_list": response[1],
      "some_list": response[2],
    };
  },
);
```

#### User class (simplified)

```
class User{
  String id;
  String email;
  List<Vehicle> vehicles = [];

  User(this.email, this.vehicles);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        displayName = json['display_name'],
}
```

## problem

in the garage screen of the app the user can add or remove vehicles. When a user adds or removes a vehicle this affects the entire flow of the app. So this `User` needs to have its `Notifier` class

#### CurrentUserNotifier

```
class CurrentUserNotifier extends StateNotifier<User> {
  final User user;

  CurrentUserNotifier(this.user) : super(null);

  void addUserVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    state..vehicles.add(vehicle);
  }

  void removeUserVehicle(int vehicleId) {
    state..vehicles.removeWhere((v) => v.id == vehicleId);
  }
}
```

#### currentUserProvider

```
final currentUserProvider = StateNotifierProvider.family<CurrentUserNotifier, User, User>((ref, user) {
  return CurrentUserNotifier(user);
});
```

Currently I am retrieving a `List<User>` and want only to have the current user to be coming from a `provider` in my app. As you see I have made a `.family` from `StateNotifierProvider` so I can perform the following thing:

#### content retrieval (mainContentFutureProvider)

```
final mainContentFutureProvider= FutureProvider<Map<String, Object>>((ref) async {
    List response = await Future.wait([
       DataController.userInfoDB.getUsers(),
       DataController.userInfoDB.getAnotherList(),
       DataController.userInfoDB.getAnotherList,
    ]);

    --->  currentUserProvider(response[0].first);

    return {
      "users": response[0],
      "some_list": response[1],
      "some_list": response[2],
    };
  },
);
```

But for any page that deals with my `User` object it needs to pass through the `user` object as parameter to my `currentUserProvider`

like:

```
press: () async {            
  ref.read(currentUserProvider(user).notifier).addUserVehicle(vehicle);
}
```

I want the provider just set the value of the `StateNotifierProvider` once, am I making a pattern/flow mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Have your `CurrentUserNotifier` like so.

```
final currentUserProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CurrentUserNotifier, User>((ref) {
  return CurrentUserNotifier();
});


class CurrentUserNotifier extends StateNotifier<User?> {

  CurrentUserNotifier() : super(null);

  void setUser(User user){
     state = user;
  }

  void addUserVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    state =  state..vehicles.add(vehicle);
  }

  void removeUserVehicle(int vehicleId) {
    state = state..vehicles.removeWhere((v) => v.id == vehicleId);
  }
}
```

Then set the `user` like so:

```
final mainContentFutureProvider= FutureProvider<Map<String, Object>>((ref) async {
    List response = await Future.wait([
       DataController.userInfoDB.getUsers(),
       DataController.userInfoDB.getAnotherList(),
       DataController.userInfoDB.getAnotherList,
    ]);
     
    ref.read(currentUserProvider.notifier).setUser(response[0].first);

    return {
      "users": response[0],
      "some_list": response[1],
      "some_list": response[2],
    };
  },
);
```

Then you can do:

```
press: () async {            
  ref.read(currentUserProvider.notifier).addUserVehicle(vehicle);
}
```

Comment: I implemented this, but I just read in the Riverpod docs that I should not call read inside the body of a provider. Does this mean I am now performing bad practise?

Comment: You can use `watch` instead of `read` in that case. Prefer `read` when you are trying to perform some action. For example, `onPressed: () {}`